# Take value from array from database

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code returned by `print_r`. Return values I need to take the number nine and pass it to a variable.

My question is, how do I take that nine put it into a variable?

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [MAX(userID)] => 9 ) )
```

Thank you for you reply.

Comment: PROTIP: In your SQL, you can do `MAX(userID) AS value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need curly braces with the parentheses in there:

```
$var = $row[0]->{'MAX(userID)'};
```

But as Rocket Hazmat states in the comments, just use `AS` to name it in the query:

```
SELECT MAX(userID) AS top FROM table
```

Then it's simpler:

```
$var = $row[0]->top;
```

Comment: i appreciate, i face the same problem and solve like this way.

Comment: Thank you all, i solved my isue...
Thank you very much